# ¿Que debo añadir al comando para organizar en orden decreciente(mayor a menor) el gráfico de barra?

Tags: r, rstudio

Hice una gráfico de barra con 10 observaciones en R-studio, usando los siguientes comandos, pero no he logrado organizar el gráfico en orden decreciente(de mayor a menor) ;

```
barras=geom_bar(aes(x=Razon,y=Ingresos),stat = "identity")
geom_bar(aes(x=reorder(Razon),y=Ingresos),stat = "identity")
ggplot(data = Base) + barras + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle =30))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Jairo a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas. En particular en tu caso agregar una muestra de tus datos 'Base', nos ayudaría a darte una respuesta adecuada. Si no puedes compartir tus datos originales, puedes cambiarlos siempre y cuando mantengas el mismo tipo y estructura.

Comment: Te falto indicarle a `reorder` justamente el vector del orden. Prueba con: `geom_bar(aes(x=reorder(Razon, -Ingresos), y=Ingresos),stat = "identity")`

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que ggplot toma el orden de factor, sin importar el orden que tenga la tabla de datos. Por ejemplo, si simulamos unos datos similares a los que tienes en la imagen

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
#Simulamos los datos
Base<-data.frame(
  Razon =letters[sample(26,10)],
  Ingresos = rnorm(10,1000,100)
)
```

Si aplicamos la función `str` sobre Base podemos ver que `Base$Razon` es de tipo factor, incluso podemos algunos de sus niveles, pero si también corremos `levels` podremos ver los niveles de `Base$Razon` y su orden

```
 str(Base)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Razon   : Factor w/ 10 levels "a","h","j","k",..: 2 6 3 7 8 1 4 5 9 10
 $ Ingresos: num  1172 1046 873 931 955 ...

 levels(Base$Razon)
 [1] "a" "h" "j" "k" "q" "t" "u" "w" "x" "z"
```

*(En caso de que la salida de `str` muestre que `Razon` es de tipo `character`, debes correr `Base$Razon<-as.factor(Base$Razon)` para poder seguir con esta explicación.)*

Si vemos la base se nota que el orden de los datos no se corresponde con el orden de los niveles

```
   Base
       Razon  Ingresos
    1      h 1171.5065
    2      t 1046.0916
    3      j  873.4939
    4      u  931.3147
    5      w  955.4338
    6      a 1122.4082
    7      k 1035.9814
    8      q 1040.0771
    9      x 1011.0683
    10     z  944.4159
```

Incluso si re ordenamos la base de mayor a menor por Ingresos el orden de los niveles de Razón se mantendrá y como vemos en seguida el orden de la gráfica no se corresponde con el de la tabla

```
#Replicamos la gráfica
barras=geom_bar(aes(x=Razon,y=Ingresos),stat = "identity")
geom_bar(aes(x=reorder(Razon),y=Ingresos),stat = "identity")
ggplot(data = Base) + barras + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle =30))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Una solución**

Es re-difinir los niveles de la variable factor (Razon) de acurdo al orden de la variable por la que deseas ordenar la gráfica (Ingresos), el siguiente código debería lograr lo que deseas

```
#Ordenamos la base de mayor a menor por Ingreso
Base<-Base[order(Base$Ingresos,decreasing = T),]

#Convertirmos a factor la columna Razón
Base$Razon<-factor(Base$Razon,levels = Base$Razon)
levels(Base$Razon)
[1] "h" "a" "t" "q" "k" "x" "w" "z" "u" "j"

#Replicamos la gráfica
barras=geom_bar(aes(x=Razon,y=Ingresos),stat = "identity")
geom_bar(aes(x=reorder(Razon),y=Ingresos),stat = "identity")
ggplot(data = Base) + barras + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle =30))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Listo con esto quedaría la gráfica ordenada.